# Folder Permissions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

I would like to apply some permissions to websites I have hosted on a Ubuntu machine

What I will be doing is create a user for each project we have, and I would like each one of them users to not have read/write access to other websites

For example this is what I done:

```
adduser mywebsite
chown -R mywebsite:www-data /var/www/html/mywebsite
chmod -R 770 /var/www/html/mywebsite
```

So, the goal is to have www-data and root access to everything, but mywebsite will only be able to view `/var/www/html/mywebsite/`, and not read or write any of the parent folders (and files)

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Oh sorry, my question was how to get that to work, when I tried `chmod -R 770 /var/www/html/mywebsite` the mywebsite user couldn't read or write either, Im not sure what im doing wrong

Comment: What does `ls -lah /var/www/html` say?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3txCdin6

Comment: Looks to me that your user dev should have full r/w/x permissions inside most of the folders, so that looks okay.  So now what are the actual permissions inside a folder?